# Vuejs: Dynamic Recursive components

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I am trying to make a custom component that call itself. i keep getting an error

`Unknown custom element: <TestRec> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

I have included a name option as you can see below but this doesn't solve the problem.

Any idea what it could be?

```
<template>
  <div>
        <h4>I am a component that can call itself below</h4>

        <v-select :items="['TestRec', 'normal']" v-model="comp"></v-select>

        <hr />
        <component :is="comp"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestRec from "./TestRec";
export default {
    name: 'New-Test-Rec', //Name tried 'Test-Rec' too. Same result
    components: {
        TestRec
    },
    data(){
        return {
            comp: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked for me when I removed `components` key and called it with its name. here is [a running example in code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/645pqml73z) and here is the code for future reference:

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <h4>I am a component that can call itself below</h4>
        <button @click="show = true">Load next</button>
    <hr />
    <component v-if="show" :is="'TestRec'"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
  name: 'TestRec',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      show: false
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Saved me from a weeks worth of headaches. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176906/how-to-import-components-dynamically-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-vue-js

Comment: I am trying to render 3 different components but not able to do like this