# Vuejs: Dynamic Recursive components (Tree Like Structure)

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js, components

I am trying to make a custom component that calls the 'list' version of itself. i keep getting an error

Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I have included a name option as you can see below but this doesn't solve the problem.

Any idea what it could be?

`TestCompList.vue` <-- The List component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>I am a list</p>

        <template v-for="block in blocks">
            <test-comp :name="block.name" :header="block.name" :more="block.more" :key="block.id"></test-comp>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestComp from './TestComp';
export default {
    name: "TestCompList",
    components: {
        TestComp
    },
    props: ['blocks'],
}
</script>
```

`TestComp.vue` <--- The Single component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>{{header}}</h3>
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <div class="mr-5" v-if="more">
            <test-comp-list :blocks="more"></test-comp-list>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestCompList from './TestCompList';
export default {
    name: "TestComp",
    props: ['header', 'name', 'more'],
    components: {
        TestCompList
    }
}
</script>
```

`Page.vue` <-- The page passing the data

```
<template>
    <div>
       <h3>Testing Recursive components</h3>

       <test-comp-list :blocks="blocks"></test-comp-list>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestCompList from "./TestCompList";
export default {
  components: {
    TestCompList
  },
  data() {
    return {
      blocks: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "test1",
          header: "test1Header"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "test2",
          header: "test2Header"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "test3",
          header: "test3Header",
          more: [
            {
              id: 4,
              name: "test4",
              header: "test4Header"
            },
            {
              id: 5,
              name: "test5",
              header: "test5Header",
              more: [
                {
                  id: 6,
                  name: "test6",
                  header: "test6Header"
                },
                {
                  id: 7,
                  name: "test7",
                  header: "test7Header"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Any ideas? 
I solved a similar problem here -> [Vuejs: Dynamic Recursive components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765656/vuejs-dynamic-recursive-components/48766844?noredirect=1#comment84539152_48766844)

But can't seem to apply the solution here.
Worst part is sometimes it seems to work and sometimes it doesn't

Help! What could i be missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a circular dependency.  Look at the documentation directly below the recursive documentation: [Circular References Between Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Circular-References-Between-Components).  You need to add a `beforeCreate` hook to pull in the child dependency at load time.

This isn't quite the recursive problem that you thought, because if it was recursive, the component would be trying to call itself.  Instead it's trying to declare a dependency on a component that, in turn, has a dependency on the component that is trying to declare the dependency; hence the "circular".

Effectively, the `vue-loader` doesn't know what to do since your dependency graph looks like:

```
Page -> TestCompList -> TestComp -> TestCompList -> TestComp -> ...
```

As the docs say, this wouldn't be a problem if you registered these components globally (but then you would have an unnecessarily broad dependency structure).  The way to fix this **without** registering globally, is to have one of the components state it's dependency requirement at runtime in a `beforeCreate` hook.

### New `TestCompList.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>I am a list</p>

        <template v-for="block in blocks">
            <TestComp :name="block.name" :header="block.name" :more="block.more" :key="block.id"></TestComp>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "TestCompList",
        props: ['blocks'],
        beforeCreate: function(){
            this.$options.components.TestComp = require("./TestComp.vue").default;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A more readable approach would be using [Webpack’s asynchronous import](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components)

All you need to do is changing the components section of `TestCompList.vue` into this:

```
        components: {
            TestComp: () => import('./TestComp.vue'),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component name does not match the tag you are using

```
name: "TestComp",

<test-comp>
```

Should be:

```
name: "test-comp",

<test-comp>
```

Comment: Did you make the change for both `TestComp` and `TestCompList`?

Comment: Yes I did for both

Comment: Vue doesn't actually care about the case, at least in `.vue` files.  I'm not sure about using the runtime version.