# Circular References Between Components Vue

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, components

I have created two components (A and B). I am trying to make them recursive. So CompA calls ComB, CompB calls CompA and so on:

```
Page -> CompA -> CompB -> CompA -> CompB -> ...
```

This is my **CompA.Vue**

```
<CompB></CompB>
```

and its `script`:

```
import CompB from './CompB';
export default {
    name: "CompA",
    components:{CompB},
    props:['items']
 },
 beforeCreate() {
        this.$options.components.CompB = require("./CompB").default;
    },
```

and this is **CompB.Vue**:

```
<v-comp-a :items="test"></v-comp-a>
```

and its `script`:

```
 import CompA from '../components/CompA'
export default {
    name: "v-comp-b",
    components:{'v-comp-a':CompA},
    props: {
        label: {
            typ:String,
            required:true
        },
        properties:{
            type:Array,
            required:true
        }
    },
```

So, the main page loads with `CompA` and I can call `CompB` from there but the problem is that I cannot call `CompA` from `CompB`. I get this error:
**Unknown custom element:v-comp-a did you register the component correctly?**

I have also imported both of the components in **App.Vue**:

```
import CompA from './components/CompA'
import CompB from './components/CompB'
```

and in script:

```
components: {
   CompA,
   CompB
}
```

and this is main page that passes data:

```
<v-comp-a :items="items"></v-comp-a>
```

I already saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810636/vuejs-dynamic-recursive-components-tree-like-structure). and read [this documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components).
I tried to show the import only since it would be very long, I also used `CompA` instead of `v-comp-a`. It did not help.

Please Help. I m starting to lose it :[

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have quite a lot of syntax errors: in *CompA.vue*:

- `beforeCreate()` should be *inside* your export default
- You are importing *CompB* in the beforeCreate hook, so remove the other import
- Don't declare *ComB* in *components*
- (There is still a comma after the last bracket but I guess that this is not the case in the actual project)

> ```
> export default {
>   name: "CompA",
>   props:['items'],
>   beforeCreate() {
>     this.$options.components.CompB = require("./CompB.vue").default;
>   }
> }
> ```

Leave *CompB.vue* as it is and you should see the error disappear.
Now they are recursive but basically *CompB* is in *CompA* is in *CompB* ...
 So making them recursive should give a recursive error.

Comment: Removing the import from CompA solved the issue. beforeCreate() was in the right place in the actual project. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

With Vue 3, you can use Async Components:

```js
export default {
  name: "CompA",
  components: {
    "CompB": defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./CompB.vue'))
  }
}
```

Documentation:

- https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#_3-x-syntax
- https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#async-components